# Binding data in TextBlock using Run endlessly like a paragraph in WP8

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the following XML file which used to bind the data in TextBlock.

```
<Guest>
  <list>
     <line index="1" name="Red Riding Hood."/>
     <line index="2" name="commonly known as Red is one of the main characters of Once
                            on a Time."/>
     <line index="3" name="Once a young."/>
     <line index="4" name="free-spirited girl who lived in a small village in the 
                            fairytale land."/>
     <line index="5" name="along with her grandmother."/>
     <line index="6" name="Red was unknowingly plagued by a curse that transformed 
                            her into a wolf with every full moon."/>
     <line index="7" name="She discovered who she really is. "/>
 </list>
</Guest>
```

And Here is the XAML;

```
<UserControl x:Class="OURBOOK.View.StoryDetail"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
 xmlns:toolkit="clrnamespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"             
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:eim="clr_namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:OURBOOK.Converter"
xmlns:ts="clr-namespace:OURBOOK.TemplateSelector"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <cv:Index2ColorBrush x:Key="Index2ColorBrush"/>
    <cv:FontsizeBigger x:Key="FontsizeBigger"/>
    <cv:VisibilityBool x:Key="VisibilityBool"/>
    <cv:Index2FontFamily x:Key="Index2FontFamily"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" >
           <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  
                    TextAlignment="Center" 
                    Foreground="White" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    Margin="20,10,10,10"/>
     </Grid>
     <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
        <ListBox x:Name="ListParagraph"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListParas}" 
             Loaded="ListParagraph_Loaded" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ts:ParagraphTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                        <ts:ParagraphTemplateSelector>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Margin="10,0"  >
                                    <TextBlock  x:Name="Detail" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Index, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                   </ts:ParagraphTemplateSelector>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So the out come of the content is displayed like following;

```
1 Red Riding Hood.
2 commonly known as Red is one of the main 
characters of Once on a Time3Once a young.
4 free-spirited girl who lived in a small 
village in the fairytale land.
5 along with her grandmother.
6 Red was unknowingly plagued by a curse    
that transformed her into a wolf with 
every full moon.
7 She discovered who she really is.
```

But I want the data to arrange like the following one by one like a paragraph; I KNOW IT IS BIT STRANGE WAY TO DO.

> 1 Red Riding Hood. 2 commonly known as  Red is one of the main
>   characters of  Once on a Time. 3 Once a young. 4 free- spirited girl
>   who lived in a small  village in the fairytale land. 5 along  with her
>   grandmother. 6 Red was unknowingly plagued by a curse that transformed
>   her  into a wolf with every full moon. 7 She  discovered who she
>   really is.

I will appreciate if any one have a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: What control are you using to go through the XML file?  An ItemsControl?

Comment: @user3602102 this `TextBlock` displays single `line`. How do you show list of `line` elements? Do you use `ItemsControl`, `ListBox`, `ListView` or something else?

Comment: @ErikElkins The     TextBlock is inside a     StackPanel

Comment: StackPanel is not an ItemsControl either. And the Title hardly matches the question content. Note that you can _edit_ a question.

Comment: Can you paste in all of your XAML?  We're interested in what surrounds your StackPanel.

Comment: @ErikElkins Updated as you requested. Thanks

Comment: Dkozl's answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change how items are stacked in a `ListBox` then you need to change `ItemsPanel` to horizontal `WrapPanel`

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListParagraph" ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"> 
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <!-- your template -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

But this will not break item in half as each item must still take one rectangle. It will only put next item in new line when it will not fit

Comment: Nothing happened. I did like you suggested. There is an error with    <WrapPanel/>    so I had to use<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>    But it was not working.

Comment: Like I said in my answer. It will not break one item across 2 rows. It will only move **whole item** to the next line when it won't fit at the end of current line. In your case, most likely, items are too long to fit more then one item in one row hence it looks like nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this,

```
   <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
           <Run Text="{Binding Path=Index, Mode=OneWay}"/>
           <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: That would not be the way I wanted. I have updated the Questions to give you more clear picture.